# Can I conditionally exit from an $asyncValidator?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form where the user needs to type in 6 characters. While he is typing, I want my directive to default to an invalid state (some $error). Once he types the 6th character, an API call is made and the state is valid only if the 6 character string matches an entry on the back end. I have the following:

```
app.directive("validSectionCode", function ($q, SectionService) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$asyncValidators.validSectionCode = function (modelValue) {
                var promise = SectionService.getSectionByCode(modelValue);
                return promise;    
            }
        }
    };
});
```

My question is how can I tell my form that the value is invalid if the length of `modelValue != 6`? As I understand, the `ngModel.$asyncValidators` waits for either a success or failure from a promise, so returning true / false has raised hell on the console. I've also tried `$q.defer.reject` as a return value, but again, errors. What is the correct thing to return if I want to make the return invalid without ever executing the API call?

Answer (score 0):

Please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/ujVJslH086ZlwM8xDDUS?p=preview

```
 app.directive("validSectionCode", function($q, $http) {
    return {
      require: "ngModel",
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$asyncValidators.validSectionCode = function(modelValue) {


          if (modelValue && modelValue.length == 6) {


            return $http.get('/api/users/' + modelValue).
            then(function resolved() {
              //username exists, this means validation fails
              return $q.reject();
            }, function rejected() {
              //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
              return true;
            });
            // value length is !=6 validation fails without calling API
          } else

          {

            return $q.reject();

          }

        }
      }
    };
  });
```